# Is there a way to update Jenkins running in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, dockerfile, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to run Jenkins in Kubernetes but the version of Jenkins is outdated. It says I need atleast version 2.138.4 for the Kubernetes plugin.

Im using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/) jenkins image from Docker hub ("jenkins/jenkins:lts"). But when I try to run this in Kubernetes it says the version is 2.60.3. I previously used a really old version of Jenkins (2.60.3) but I updated my Dockerfile to use the latest image. After that I build the image again and threw it to Kubernetes. I even delete my Kubernetes Deployment and Service before deploying them again.
I'm currently working in a development environment using Minikube.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

ENV JENKINS_USER admin
ENV JENKINS_PASS admin

# Skip initial setup
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false


COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -qqy apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common 
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository \
  "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) \
  stable"
RUN apt-get update  -qq \
  && apt-get install docker-ce -y
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
RUN apt-get clean
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
USER jenkins
```

The Kubernetes deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          image: mikemanders/my-jenkins-image:1.0
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
          ports:
            - name: http-port
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: jnlp-port
              containerPort: 50000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jenkins-home
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          emptyDir: {}
```

And the Kubernetes Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: jenkins
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

I think my Kubernetes configuration are good, so I'm guessing it has something to do with Docker?

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

To [update a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment), you need new `Docker` image based on the new `Jenkins` release:

```
docker build -t mikemanders/my-jenkins-image:1.1 .
docker push mikemanders/my-jenkins-image
kubectl set image deployment/jenkins mikemanders/my-jenkins-image=1.1 --record
```

### `Kubernetes` deploys `images` not `dockerfiles`

As per [Images man](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/)

> You create your Docker image and push it to a registry before referring to it in a Kubernetes pod.
>
> The `image` property of a container supports the same syntax as the `docker` command does, including private registries and tags.

So, you need an image to deploy.

### Update your image

To update your image in registry, use `docker build -t` and `docker push`:

```
docker build -t mikemanders/my-jenkins-image:1.1
docker push mikemanders/my-jenkins-image
```

It will rebuild the image with updated `jenkins/jeinkis:lts`. Then image will be uploaded to the [container registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry).

The catch is that you are updating the image version (e.g. `1.0`->`1.1`) before updating the cluster.

Comment: Don't you need to explicitly push the local copy of the image built to the registry?

Comment: No you don't need to push it. You can use local images for your Kubernetes. But if you want to deploy it to a cloud provider you will need to push it to a registry (Docker hub for example).

Comment: According to your config, looks like you use hub.docker.com as registry, isn't it?

Comment: @Yasen thanks for your answer, can't believe I didn't think of the versions.

Comment: @Yasen true I am using hub.docker.com. Your answer worked so I have accepted it. Thanks